# Unterschied zwischen „Rezension“ und „Bewertung“

Tags: difference

Wenn man ein Produkt auf amazon.de anschaut, hat es zum Beispiel „65 Sternebewertungen“, aber wenn man darauf klickt, ist der Titel eigentlich „Kundenrezensionen“. Ich wundere mich langsam was genau der Unterschied ist.

Unter den folgenden Kategorien zum Beispiel: Restaurant, Rock Konzert, Roman, Theaterstück, Fitnessstudio - welche haben lieber eine Bewertung, und welche lieber eine Rezension?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eine **Bewertung** im Sinne von Amazon funktioniert wie eine Schul-**Note**, die über Bewertungssterne vorgenommen wird. Sie ist mit zwei drei Klicks erledigt. Sie wird im Internet in kumulierter Form veröffentlicht, indem der Mittelwert aller vorgenommenen Bewertungen neben oder unter dem Produkt erscheint.

Eine **Rezension** - wieder nach Amazon - ist eine mehr oder weniger ausführliche **Besprechung** in Textform. Ursprünglich wurden und werden Rezensionen zu neu erschienenen Büchern, Filmen, Aufführungen wie z.B. Konzerten geschrieben und in Zeitungen veröffentlicht. Heute kann man alle nur denkbaren Produkte und Anbieter 'rezensieren', auch Kochtöpfe, Nagelstudios und Klopapier.

Auch in einer Rezension wird etwas bewertet, so gesehen ist die Amazonsche Sprachwahl nur eingeschränkt übertragbar. Das Wort "Rezension" klingt kompetenter als das einfache Wort "Besprechung", aber das ist nur die übliche Augenwischerei, die es in jeder Werbung gibt, denn darum geht es letztlich: Die Kunden **werben**, meistens für das angebotene Produkt. Für den Anbieter ist es schön, wenn er diese Werbung frei Haus geliefert bekommt, und viele Kunden vertrauen sowohl Bewertungen als auch 'Rezensionen' weitgehend.

Ob ein Anbieter - z.B. ein Fitnessstudio - eine Bewertung oder eine Rezension bevorzugen würde, lässt sich nicht allgemein sagen und hängt von der Architektur der jeweiligen Internetseite ab. Am besten ist in jedem Fall eine hohe Bewertung (5/5 Sterne), verbunden mit einer nicht zu ausführlichen, aber eindeutig positiven "Rezension", falls die Seite das erlaubt.

Comment: "so gesehen ist die Amazonsche Unterscheidung willkürlich" - so würde ich das nicht sagen. Zwar ist der Übergang durchaus fließend, aber werden beide Begriffe zugleich verwendet, würde ich in jedem Fall (auch abseits von Amazon) intuitiv davon ausgehen, dass sich hinter der "Bewertung" ein eher kurzgefasstes Fazit (oftmals sogar eben nur eine Punkte-/Sternezahl/Schulnote/...) verbirgt, während die "Rezension" eine ausführlichere Besprechung bezeichnet (in der übrigens vielleicht gar keine *Bewertung* vorgenommen wird, sondern mir lediglich die Erfahrungen mit dem Testsubjekt geschildert ...

Comment: ... werden, auf deren Grundlage ich mir dann eine eigene Meinung bilden kann - auch bei Amazon).

Comment: @Ralf Joerres Sie beschreiben hier lediglich die Ausführung einer "Bewertung", aber nicht was eine Bewertung als solche darstellen soll. Ihre Beschreibung einer "Rezension" ist ebenfalls nicht erklärt, sondern Ihre Wahrnehmung einer Rezension.

Comment: @Cyber: Ja, und genau das wollte ich liefern, nicht eine objektive, objektivierte, standardisierte, enzyklopädisierte, generalisierte Erklärung, nur eine aus dem Handgelenk geschüttelte Augenblickserklärung für Amazon. Ich fand die Frage zu unpräzise gestellt, um intensiv darauf einzugehen. Rein praktisch sind sehr viele Amazon-'Rezensionen' lediglich Erfahrungsberichte. Da passt die Bezeichnung 'Rezension' eigentlich nicht.

Comment: @O. R. Mapper: Ja, stimmt, will mal versuchen, das zu berücksichtigen. Andererseits. Wenn jemand schreibt, "das Gerät ließ sich nicht einschalten", dann ist das eine Erfahrung des Kunden mit diesem Gerät, die dann aber vom Leser bewertend genutzt (verstanden) wird.

Answer (score 1):

Eine **Bewertung** kann eine objektive meist aber subjektive Einschätzung unter Berücksichtigung von klar definierten Vorgaben oder Kriterien sein, z.b. bei Amazon eine Skala in Form von Sternen.

Die Bewertung eines Gegenstands steht meistens im Verhältnis zu anderen Gegenständen, dabei kann aber muss der Gegenstand nicht im selben Kontext stehen. Bei Amazon ist der kleinste gemeinsame Nenner eines Artikels die Eigenschaft: ein Artikel wird angeboten, dieser wird beschrieben, man kann es kaufen und es wird geliefert.

Dabei bezieht sich die Bewertung meistens auf diese Eigenschaften:

1. Wurde er wie beschrieben geliefert?
2. Gab es Probleme beim Kauf?
3. War die Lieferung schnell und zufriedenstellend, wurde geliefert?

Eine **Rezension** ist meist nur subjektiv und benötigt keinen Kriterienrahmen, z.b. der beigefügte Text zu einer Bewertung. Eine Rezension kann / sollte sich auf die Eigenschaft des Gegenstands beziehen, da es aber keine festen Kriterien gibt, kann man dies auch umgehen.